# Getting Param Name in error when using @Validated on @RequestParam in Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I am developing a REST API and want to validate some `@RequestParam` using 
`@Validated` annotation of Spring.

But the problem is that `@Validated` results in `ConstraintViolationException` due to which I cannot get details of FieldError so that I can check which Field has error and give proper error object as per requested parameters.

Here is the sample code I am using for handling this validations:

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class Controller{

   @GetMapping("/getValue")
   public Response controller(@RequestParam @NotNull String username,
     @RequestParam String value, @RequestParam @NotNull @Size(max=21) String id, @RequestParam @Pattern(regexp="")String value){

   return responseObject;
}
```

**ValidationHandlerClass**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerValidation{


@ExpectionHandler
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Set<ConstraintViolation> validateRequest(ConstraintViolationException e){

  return e.getConstraintViolations();
}
```

Can anyone help me how get FieldErrors in such Validation scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get field name when javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException is thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555057/get-field-name-when-javax-validation-constraintviolationexception-is-thrown)

Comment: @javaguy : If you follow the answers of the question, then it is solving the problem of what I am looking for.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. 
I got my answer my adding following as Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigProps{

@Bean
public Validator validator(){
 return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean 
public MethodValidationPostProcesssor methodValidationPostProcessor(){
  MethodVaidationPostProccessor methodPostProcessor = new MethodValidationProcessor();
  methodPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
  return methodPostProcessor;
}
```

Comment: How does it actually solve it? Does `ConstraintViolationException` is being constructed differently? Please elaborate.