# How we can get the invalid value that we have pass in the request from Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>>

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Currently, I am validating my request using javax validation.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> constraintViolations = validator
            .validate(Request);
```

So from constraint violations I want two things,

1. constraint `violation.getPropertyPath()` which will return which fields is violating
2. I want the invalid value that I was passing in the request for the fields from the `constraintViolations` variable

So how we can get the invalid value?

For 2. I tried using `constraintViolation.getInvalidValue()` this but it is giving like `com.practice.domain.PaymentInstrumentRequest@258d8cb5`

I want specific value that I have passed in that field.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555057/get-field-name-when-javax-validation-constraintviolationexception-is-thrown

Comment: Thanks Hulk, I refer that but currently when I am doing constraintViolation.getInvalidValue() , it is returning whole request data that I am passing. I only want that field value.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell more than that - have never used this myself. Perhaps it would help to show an example for a constraint and input violating it, and a sample output for what exactly you want to find out about the violation.